# Finding executable in PATH with Rust

Tags: rust

In Python I can:

```py
from distutils import spawn

cmd = spawn.find_executable("commandname")
```

I tried something like the code below, but it it assumes you're on unix-like system with `/usr/bin/which` available(also it involves execution of external command which I want to avoid):

```
use std::process::Command;

let output = Command::new("which")
                      .arg("commandname")
                      .unwrap_or_else(|e| /* handle error here */)
```

What is the simplest way to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd probably grab the environment variable and iterate through it, returning the first matching path:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn find_it<P>(exe_name: P) -> Option<PathBuf>
    where P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    env::var_os("PATH").and_then(|paths| {
        env::split_paths(&paths).filter_map(|dir| {
            let full_path = dir.join(&exe_name);
            if full_path.is_file() {
                Some(full_path)
            } else {
                None
            }
        }).next()
    })
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", find_it("cat"));
    println!("{:?}", find_it("dog"));
}
```

This is probably ugly on Windows as you'd have to append the `.exe` to the executable name. It should also potentially be extended to only return items that are executable, which is again platform-specific code.

Reviewing the [Python implementation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/distutils/spawn.py), it appears they also support an absolute path being passed. That's up to you if the function should support that or not.

A quick search on [crates.io](https://crates.io) returned one crate that may be useful: [quale](https://crates.io/crates/quale), although it currently says

> currently only works on Unix-like operating systems.

It wouldn't surprise me to find out there are others.

---

Here's some ugly code that adds `.exe` to the end if it's missing, but only on Windows.

```
#[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
fn enhance_exe_name(exe_name: &Path) -> Cow<Path> {
    exe_name.into()
}

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
fn enhance_exe_name(exe_name: &Path) -> Cow<Path> {
    use std::ffi::OsStr;
    use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;

    let raw_input: Vec<_> = exe_name.as_os_str().encode_wide().collect();
    let raw_extension: Vec<_> = OsStr::new(".exe").encode_wide().collect();

    if raw_input.ends_with(&raw_extension) {
        exe_name.into()
    } else {
        let mut with_exe = exe_name.as_os_str().to_owned();
        with_exe.push(".exe");
        PathBuf::from(with_exe).into()
    }
}

// At the top of the `find_it` function:
// let exe_name = enhance_exe_name(exe_name.as_ref());
```

Comment: Blindly using `.exe` isn't *really* correct.  You're supposed to use the `PATHEXT` environment variable, which is a `;`-separated list of file extensions that are considered "executable".  Sadly, you have to be careful because `CreateProcess` (which is what Rust's `Command` type is backed by, AFAIK) only supports native executable types, so it can't be used like it can on UNIX (*e.g.* to invoke shell scripts).  So, unless you're also intending to write your own code using `ShellExecute` (which Rust doesn't use I-don't-know-why), you should probably limit yourself to `.COM;.EXE`.

Comment: @DK. cross-platform work is hard! For whatever it's worth, the code here mimics what Python is doing, although I don't know how great the Windows support of Python is to start with. Maybe we should submit this back up to a crate (like quale?).

Comment: Yeah, I realised after writing that (when I'd run out of characters) that there's really no way to do this *properly* in Rust without writing actual Win32 code, because even if you correctly find `commandname.py` or something, you can't actually invoke it.  I suppose that's what you get when executing scripts is a shell feature instead of a kernel feature...

Answer (score 19):

I found a crate that solves the problem: [`which`](https://crates.io/crates/which). It includes Windows support, even accounting for `PATHEXT`.