# What is the best way to check if an executable exists for `std::process::Command`?

Tags: rust

I want to create a `std::process::Command` and check whether an executable actually exists at that location before actually spawning the `Command` later. What would be the pragmatic way to do this?

I have this code:

```
let c = std::process::Command::new("my_exe");
// something here
c.spawn().unwrap();
```

I want to be able to validate the `my_exe` path when creating the `Command` and then `spawn` way later.

Comment: What is "that location"? When you are telling for example your shell to run some program it is searched in paths specified in `$PATH`. Do you wish to manually check this paths and see if there is an executable with given name?

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to do $PATH manipulation to try out all the locations. Can this be done without external dependencies and just by using some function which does this for me?

Comment: "I don't want to do $PATH manipulation to try out all the locations." 

That's what happens under the hood anyway.

Comment: I know that's what's happening under the hood but I would expect there is an already existing standard library call which does this for me

Answer (score 7):

> check whether an executable actually exists at that location before actually spawning the `Command`.

**Don't** as that's a [time-of-check to time-of-use race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). Instead, check the error value from executing the `Command`: [Check if a command is in PATH/executable as process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35045996/155423).

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do that but I guess it's the only sensible solution.

Comment: There may still be cases where you'd like to check at the start of the program. For example, if you have a long running process that calls out to a couple of different programs, you don't want your user to find out after some time-consuming first step has already run that one of the dependent programs is missing.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to check if a file is present in the working directory, you can use [`Path::exists`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.exists), as described in [How to check whether a path exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384594/155423).

Also, `Command::spawn()` takes a mutable reference to `self` so `c` needs to be mutable.

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::process::Command;

if Path::new("PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE").exists() {
    let mut c = Command::new("PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE");
    // do something
    c.spawn().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case of using an executable based on the `PATH`. See also [Finding executable in PATH with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37498864/155423)

Answer (score -5):

Use the [is_executable](https://crates.io/crates/is_executable) crate:

```rust
use is_executable::IsExecutable;
use std::fs;

let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();

for path in paths {
    let file_path = path.unwrap().path();
    if file_path.is_executable() {
        println!("File: {:?} is executable!", file_path);
    } else {
        println!("File: {:?} is _not_ executable!", file_path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the other downvoted answer, this doesn't handle checking if the executable is in PATH, it only works with absolute and relative paths.